# repeating input

Tags: python

I want to program it like that so while taking input of num1,num2 and operation if user doesn't give input in appropriate type it ask the user again for input.

```
operation=(input('1.add\n2.subtract\n3.multiply\n4.divide'))
num1 =int(input("Enter first number: "))
num2 = int(input("Enter second number: "))

if operation == "add" or operation == '1' :
   print(num1,"+",num2,"=", (num1+num2))
elif operation =="subtract" or operation == '2':
   print(num1,"-",num2,"=", (num1-num2))
elif operation =="multiply" or operation == '3':
   print(num1,"*",num2,"=", (num1*num2))
elif operation =="divide" or operation == '4':
   print(num1,"/",num2,"=", (num1/num2))
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to test multiple variables against a value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15112125/how-to-test-multiple-variables-against-a-value)

Comment: Start your Python, enter `"2" == "1" or "add"` and consider the result.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `in` keyword.

Ex:

```
>>> "1" in ["1","add"]
True
>>> "add" in ["1","add"]
True
```

Modify code like:

```
 operation=(input('1.add\n2.subtract\n3.multiply\n4.divide'))

    num1 = int(input("Enter first number: "))
    num2 = int(input("Enter second number: "))

    if operation in ["1","add"] :
       print(num1,"+",num2,"=", (num1+num2))
    elif operationi in ["2", "subtract"]:
       print(num1,"-",num2,"=", (num1-num2))
    elif operation in ["3", "multiply"]:
       print(num1,"*",num2,"=", (num1*num2))
    elif operation in ["4", "divide"]:
       print(num1,"/",num2,"=", (num1/num2))
    else:
        print("Invalid Input")
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
 operation=(input('1.add\n2.subtract\n3.multiply\n4.divide'))

    num1 = int(input("Enter first number: "))
    num2 = int(input("Enter second number: "))

    if operation == "1" or operation == "add" :
       print(num1,"+",num2,"=", (num1+num2))
    elif operation == "2" or operation == "subtract":
       print(num1,"-",num2,"=", (num1-num2))
    elif operation == "3" or operation == "multiply":
       print(num1,"*",num2,"=", (num1*num2))
    elif operation == "4" or operation == "divide":
       print(num1,"/",num2,"=", (num1/num2))
    else:
        print("Invalid Input")
```

**Explanation:**

In your code, **IF** will check condition-1 or condition-2 are True or False

```
if operation == "1" or operation == "add"
```

here,

**condition-1:** `operation == "1"`

**condition-2:** `operation == "add"`

```
if operation == "1" or operation == "add"
```

here,

**condition-1:** `operation == "1"`

**condition-2:** `"add"  # Always True as string contains elements.`

Comment: it is better to use `operation in ["1","add"]` rather than `operation == "1" or operation == "add" `.

Answer (score 0):

This code is valid because in Python values are either truthy and falsy. However, the syntax for multicondition if clause is wrong. It should be `if a == something and b == anotherthing`.

So it will be as follows.

```py
if operation == "1" or operation == "add" :
    print(num1,"+",num2,"=", (num1+num2))
```

Comment: it is better to use `operation in ["1","add"]` rather than `operation == "1" or operation == "add" `.

Comment: I know, however, the requester didn't ask for it. He said he cannot use 2 statements, that's why I mentioned this way. Nevertheless, you're absolutely right.